# AWS API Gateway Policy Per Header

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to have a policy on an API Gateway that would throttle requests based on a header value. For example, header value "AAA" would be allowed up to 10 requests per day, "BBB", 20 requests. Is this possible? How can I achieve this? Note: I am trying to avoid writing a lambda function for this purpose, because then I would need to keep state, etc.

Comment: Have u found a good solution for this? Thanks

Comment: Usage plans, yes!

Comment: But, usage plans involve API Keys, one API Key per user, right? What if I want to let users do it without issuing any API Keys?

Comment: Well, the only way I know is by using a lambda function.

Comment: use a lambda function to process the header and set different limit per header? you also have to remember users' ip / device and also number of calls for that day, right?

Comment: Indeed, no other way that I can think of. You can always store state on Redis, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172539/discussion-between-jun-and-ricardo-peres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API Gateway has Usage Plans, which support what you are attempting to do.

Each usage plan can have a throttling limit, which restricts requests per second and burst rate. Usage plans can also have quotas, which would allow you to add limits on requests per day.

API Gateway allows you to add API Keys to a usage plan. API Keys are sent HTTP header (`x-api-key`).

You can find more details in the [Usage Plans for API Gateway launch blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-usage-plans-for-amazon-api-gateway/) and [API Gateway Usage Plan docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html).

Comment: What if I want to impose rate limit for the user based on user ID or any other header key (considering the users are more than 50k)?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an API Key? It is like letting users sample the product without having to issue any API Key.